# assembly on X86 machines, Windows vs Linux

Tags: assembly, x86, virus

Are they the same?

Longer version :

Say I wrote, in assembly, on a windows machine, a small app that all it does is add 1+1 and stores it in a register. THEN, I write the exact same code on a Linux machine. Would it work?

Im thinking yes, because at the hardware level, its the same machine, so the 'language of the hardware' (forgive the inexactness) would be the same.

So Im thinking a virus targeting windows but written in assembly wouldnt just be a windows virus.

Comment: Someone's been reading some Neal Stephenson!

Comment: No, Neil Stephenson would have suggested a computer virus that can give you a fever.

Comment: Ive never heard of Neal Stephenson, but will look him up next time Im at the library.

Comment: followup question : would learning one be learning both (to a high degree, at least)? Or are we apples and oranges. From the answers so far, its the act of compiling that generates much of the difference.

Comment: @jason: Yes, if you learn to write assembly code for Windows, than you know a lot of writing assembly code for any platform. But if you intend to write a more sophisticated program, you are probably going to need to use the APIs of the platform, and these might be very different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

programs written in assembler on windows are not binary compatible with linux... you need to compile(assemble) them again on linux, but keep in mind that there are differences between assemblers.. they differently handle for example parts for declaring code, data, bss

windoes execs don't run natively on linux (you can run them in wine, but they are gonna be sandboxed)

Answer (score 11):

A virus will most certainly need to interact with the operating system, and use its API. Hence it is highly platform-dependant.

In addition, an executable also has a header, and this will depend on the targeted OS. If you would create a more or less empty EXE file in Windows, this would not run (not even start) under Linux.

Comment: People have written proof-of-concept worms and viruses that operate cross-platform either by leveraging a high level environment that can be expected to be widely present, or by doing platform detection and running the appropriate part of a multi-platform payload. 2600 had an article about one circa 10 years ago, and I've seen a white paper since then.

Comment: The original Morris worm in 1988 was multi-platform, running on Vax BSD and on Suns.

Answer (score 9):

Yes and no.

The small snippet that adds 1+1 and stores it in a register is going to be exactly the same machine code -- that is, the code that run on the processor is the same no matter what the operating system.

However, you need to surround that code with other bits that interact with the OS to make your program meaningful -- you would never know that your code actually correctly stored `2` in `eax` if it didn't output to somewhere, for example.

Interestingly, projects like Wine allow for cross-platform interoperability by providing under Linux the same API calls that the program would expect to find under Windows, as well as providing the appropriate logic to allow Linux to properly decode a Windows executable. So, with Wine support, some Windows viruses can actually run under Windows. It may take some work, but you can make it happen.

And no, Wine doesn't have to recompile the Windows programs -- it does, in fact, run the machine code stored in the EXEs directly on the processor.

Comment: Years ago, I played World of Warcraft on a Linux box using Wine.
It worked almost flawlessly, but the character's legs wouldn't animate properly for some reason.

Comment: @Kalamane, it's probably because WoW calls some strange Direct3D APIs for the leg rendering that doesn't have any equivalency in OpenGL (Vulkan was initially released in 2015).

Answer (score 3):

The language itself is pretty much the same, but the operator instructions are different. The tutorial at http://asm.sourceforge.net/intro/hello.html has a pretty good explanation of this.

```
section    .text
    global _start           ;must be declared for linker (ld)

_start:                 ;tell linker entry point

    mov edx,len ;message length
    mov ecx,msg ;message to write
    mov ebx,1   ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov eax,4   ;system call number (sys_write)
    int 0x80    ;call kernel

    mov eax,1   ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int 0x80    ;call kernel

section .data

msg db  'Hello, world!',0xa ;our dear string
len equ $ - msg         ;length of our dear string
```

This is different than the DOS hello world program because of the OS specific things(like int 0x80).

Comment: What does _"the operator instructions are different"_ mean?

Comment: @stakx – I think he meant “operating system instructions”.

Answer (score 1):

Although you may be writing x86 assembly, you'll still be using a different assembler depending on which operating system you are using, and they'll have different features, so writing in assembler on Windows wouldn't necessarily be the same as what you'd write in Linux, though I'd assume they'd be rather similar.

Comment: The features of the assembler shouldn't matter, as the translation from assembly to machine code should be the same.  It's the other things, like file format and system calls, that will be different.

Answer (score 1):

The assembly language is largely the same and similar. However, neither Windows nor Linux would try to execute an arbitrary file. Most modern operating system refuses to execute a program, unless it have the proper executable headers (e.g. PE or ELF).

In Windows, a file needs to have the correct extension (e.g. .exe, .dll, .com) and the file need to be layout conforming to the Portable Executable (PE) format before Windows even attempt to execute the file.

In Linux, a file needs to conform to the ELF format (Executable and Linkable Format) and have the execute permission bit (can be set/unset using chmod).

In practice, this means Windows which doesn't recognize ELF format would refuse to execute a Linux program; and Linux will refuse to execute a PE/Windows program unless you have Wine. A virus written in assembly would need to be *reassembled* (be run through the assembler) to the correct executable format (PE or ELF) to suit the OS.

After that, then you have the problem of differing function call convention between Windows and Linux (and even between different versions of Windows and different version of Linux); also different set of System Call API and different methods to do system calls for even the most basic things. In practice, it is near impossible to write an assembly code that is portable between Windows and Linux, since even basic operations like printing Input/Output is different.

Answer (score 1):

The x86 instructions will do the same thing.

But where things are located in memory will be different, and what your code can access.
Operating system services will be different as it how you invoke them.

So if you could get the same binary code on both then you could for example write code to add up all the numbers from 1-100 and that would work, but the mechanism for printing that out would vary considerably.

Answer (score 0):

The following are quotes from: [Introduction to Linux Intel Assembly Language](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/50/LinuxAssembly.html#tthFrefAAC)

- Things are similar under other operating systems. Using the Microsoft or Turbo compilers, for example, assembly language source files have the suffix .asm, object files have the suffix .obj, etc.
- **NASM** is available for both Unix and MS Windows. For that matter, even ***as*** can be used under Windows, since it is part of the **gcc** package and that is available for Windows under the name cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

The assembly for all operating systems can be same, assuming there's portability layer with implementations for every operating system you're supporting.

Though, if you're planning about super-compatible binaries like I do.. ELF and PE -formats are entirely different from each other, and it will prevent same executable from running on different operating systems. Though this can be solved by writing a portable program loader.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same processor and as a result the same instructions for doing your add 1+1 yes.

and it is likely possible that you can use similar enough tools to have the same assembly source at least for that instruction.  But the executable file format, which contains not only the bytes to be executed but other stuff are different between the operating systems.  Different tools are used to create the different executable files/containers.  That is if you are trying to execute a complete program.  If you have a virus or other evil program that takes advantage of some malloc in the operating system where there is a way to get the OS to execute code, well the bytes of that code are not going to contain this executable wrapper, those bytes are just the instructions you want to run.  So in that sense they would again be the same bytes, but the exploit to get into the operating system (or a driver), is likely operating system dependent and your exploit would be operating system dependent.